# Importing Figure plot from another script for MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, loops, user-interface, figure

I have a rather large MATLAB script that I now need to create a GUI for.

I have several figure plots named `figure(1), figure(2)` etc already in a script and I now want to place all of these figures in the GUI menu.

I want to create a G.U.I for data in a script I already have written. When I go to file>new>GUI it creates a blank GUI in a separate script. I want to concatenate everything together so I can work on my G.U.I design within the same script or work with the G.U.I script such that it calls my figure names/variables etc for the main script i've been working on already.

I don't need a push button or a controller, I just need these figures to be displayed automatically upon GUI initialisation. Here is an example of the figures i'd like to include in the single G.U.I window:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really understand your question, but this what I thought you want to do, see if it helps:

```
% two random data
dat1 = rand(1,10);
dat2 = rand(1,10);

fig = figure('MenuBar','None');
Plots = uimenu(fig, 'Label', 'Plots'); % Menu
% Its Submenus
uimenu(Plots, 'Label', 'Plot 1', 'Callback', @(~,~) plot(dat1, 'r'));
uimenu(Plots, 'Label', 'Plot 2', 'Callback', @(~,~) plot(dat2, 'b'));
```

[image]

Comment: Slightly helpful. I want to create a G.U.I for data in a script I already have written. When I go to file>new>GUI it creates a blank GUI in a separate script. I want to concatenate everything together so I can work on my G.U.I design within the same script or work with the G.U.I script such that it calls my figure names/variables etc for the main script i've been working on already. Hope that is clearer.

Comment: Added an image for clarity.

Comment: If you want to keep using your script and not change it to a function, there are two ways (depending on how the script interacts with the graphs): 1. calling your script from the GUI(DE) functions. 2. Using `uicontrol` (as I did above) and implementing the GUI without defining any new functions.
 I suggest the second one.

Comment: Alternatively if you only want to put the graphs in a single window, you can use `subplot`, and you won't need the hassle of involving with the GUI(DE).

Comment: I don't just want the plots though. Eventually I want to have dynamic text and drop down menus. Do you know of any useful resources which help me learn how to call my variables from the other script into GUI(DE) so I can create a GUI for them?

Comment: The reason you don't have access to the variables in your script from the the auto-generated GUI or any other function is that each function has its own workspace, which is separate from the **Base** workspace. Literally, the only interaction is by function inputs and outputs. However MATLAB also provides some other utilities such as `assignin`, `evalin` or **global variables**. However they are not recommended and should not be used very often because they will mess with the code at some point. For example global variables are VERY slow. But for simple tasks or debuging they may be useful.